# Javascript syntax : Nested callback

Tags: javascript, syntax, callback

I would like to know if there is a way to write the following code quicker.

items.getAll() callback has to take the same arguments as database.query() callback. So I just would like to "rethrow" the callback without changing it.

```
items.getAll = function(callback){
    database.query('SELECT * FROM items', function(err, rows){
        callback(err, rows);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the callback directly:

```
    database.query('SELECT * FROM items', callback);
```

An even shorter way available in modern JavaScript runtimes (that is, not old IE):

```
items.getAll = database.query.bind(database, "SELECT * FROM items");
```

Comment: @Nicolas no problem - see the addition I made to the answer.

Comment: Ok thx, as it's server side code, I should not have compatibility issues. Will read a bit about bind().